# How can i make a botton go from point A to point B in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Im trying to make a button go from point A to point B, but i need a soft movement, not a jump. Like a tranlation. How can i do it?

Comment: your_button.animate().x(50f).y(100f);  keep x and y value as you wish

Comment: thanks, but theres a way to control the speed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        make changes as per your need


        Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 500,0, 0);
        animation.setDuration(1000);
        animation.setFillAfter(true);
        yourButton.startAnimation(animation);
        yourButton.setVisibility(0);

    OR
    You can create Translate animation using ObjectAnimator. check link for more information

    ObjectAnimator transAnimation= ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(YourButton, propertyName, fromX, toX);
    transAnimation.setDuration(3000);//set duration
    transAnimation.start();//start animation

Example
ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(yourButton, "translationX", 0,200); and then 
 anim.setDuration(3000);
 anim.start();
```

Comment: Thats exatly what i want, thanks :)